# Error linking curl cross compilation

Tags: c++, linux, windows, curl, cross-compiling

I have a problem while linking curl in my cross compiler on a linux server. I get this error message :

> z:/usr/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libcurl.a(easy.o):(.text+0xfe):
>   undefined reference to libssh2_init
>   z:/usr/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libcurl.a(easy.o):(.text+0x2bd):
>   undefined reference to libssh2_exit
>   z:/usr/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   z:/usr/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libcurl.a(easy.o):
>   bad reloc address 0x0 in section .data

I compile like this :`wine64 /usr/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe main.cpp -o test -lcurl -L"/usr/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/libcurl.a" -DCURL_STATICLIB -lws2_32`
The code I use to test is this one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl.h>
using namespace std;

size_t writeCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size *nmemb);
    return size *nmemb;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
string got;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.fr");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &got);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
cout << "Source code of https://www.google.fr:" << endl << endl << got << endl;
while(1);
return 0;
}
```

The thing is I have a problem with libssh2 but I don't use it and don't need it and when I compile on windows I don't have this problem...

Comment: Are you certain the libcurl you use when compiling on windows was built with the same options as the one in your cross-toolchain?

Comment: @Frank It is exactely the same... I use ssh to connect to my server so can it come from there?

Comment: The only difference is that on my windows I compile 32bits and on my server I compile 64bits